# Jquery radial animated bar on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am looking to create a radial bar that fills to a set percentage when a person scrolls to it, I am currently using WOW.js to handle my scrolling animations and it would be great if I would comehow incorporate it using that.

Edit:

I want this to display and animate to a percent when I scroll to it. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CU7KM/)

```
$(".dial").knob({
    readOnly: true,
    fgColor: "#00ABC6",
    bgColor: "#666666",
    thickness: 0.2
});
```

Comment: You want it to smoothly increase from 0  to the value on page load ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this after your `knob` declaration :

```
$({percentage: 0}).animate({percentage: $(".dial").val()}, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing:'swing',
    step: function() 
    {
        $('.dial').val(Math.ceil(this.percentage)).trigger('change');
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CU7KM/448/)**

EDIT :

From your comment bellow :

```
$(function() {
    $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function() { 
        var $anchor = $(this); 
        $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
                scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top 
            }, 
            1500, 
            'easeInOutExpo',
            function () { //here is your callback on animation complete
                // here you include the code
            }
        ); 
        return false; // this does the same as event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: So if i wanted to have this trigger when they scroll to a specific section would i target the #section class?

Comment: You can call put this into any event callback you want

Comment: I rather new to Query , this is the function is use for my page scrolling animation ,would i bind a click event to this?

$(function() {
    $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

Comment: see my edit... You can give your animation a function to execute on complete ([see the doc](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)) (but be aware that this will not be called when scrolled manually)

Comment: So if i wanted to do both i would have to have two separate functions?

Comment: I did a little more research and found this , https://coderwall.com/p/tozq6g  . Im unsure as to if it would work once i scroll to the DIV i want and if i clicked my nav links.

Comment: Ok I'll try to make a jsfiddle of it

Comment: Ok this is it : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CU7KM/449/) ... Tell me if you don't understand something

Comment: This is great i think im starting to understand more now , if i had more than one dial and i wanted to off set the animations would i give each a class name? and do a seperate function? inside the animation function?

Comment: I would keep the class, but then pass it as parameter within the function : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CU7KM/451/)

Comment: So inside the brackets of the amimation function seperated by commas?

function runLoaderAnimation(dial1 , dial2 ,dial3)

Comment: or inside the callback ?  runLoaderAnimation();

Comment: just like I did in my last demo

Comment: Sorry about that i missed the demo , thank you very much for your time youve been a great help.

Comment: IF i wanted teh animation to trigger when the div hits the top of the page with an offset of around 60 pixels how would i do that?

Comment: Just add this value to the test as an simple integer.